# Create New Numpy 2D Array given same value in first entry

Tags: python, arrays, python-3.x, numpy

I have this NumPy 2D array:

```
array([[  113,  1915],
   [  113,  3314],
   [  113, 53081],
   ...,
   [97267,  4112],
   [97267, 37556],
   [97267,  4786]])
```

That I want to group to create a new 2D Array such that each row shares the same first entry in the original 2D Array. For example, I want the following for the above 2D array:

```
    array([[1915, 3314, 53081],
   ...,
   [4112, 37556, 4786]])
```

How can I do this?

Comment: Is the input array really two dimensions, rather than three? And you really want the output array to be two dimensions as well, rather than one? In that case... what is the rule that tells you to put `[1915, 3314, 53081]` in the first row of the output, rather than e.g. only including `[1915, 3314]`, or continuing to `[1915, 3314, 53081, 4112]`?

Comment: @KarlKnechtel both the input and output are 2D arrays. Do you mean 3 columns instead of dimensions?

Comment: No, I meant three dimensions, which you deny. So now my question is, why is it 3 columns, instead of any other number of columns?

Answer (score 0):

This is not possible for arbitrary entries. For example,

```
x = np.array([[0,1],
              [0,2],
              [1,3],
              [1,4],
              [1,5],])
```

Hence, it must be an assumption that there is the same number of 0s and 1s. Correct? If so, then something like this should do it:

```
x = np.array([[  113,  1915],
   [  113,  3314],
   [  113, 53081],
   [97267,  4112],
   [97267, 37556],
   [97267,  4786]])
n = (x[0,0]==x[:,0]).sum() #Check how many 113s occur. 
y = x[:,1].reshape(len(x)//n,3)

print(y)
```